# Can I host a file or folder on another person's domain?

Tags: javascript, security, hosting, dns, system-administration

I don't think this is possible, but it never hurts to ask.

Is there any way for me to host a file (or folder) on someone else's domain (with their permission, of course)? For example, if their site is hosted at `www.example.com`, I would like to host a file at `www.example.com/foo.html`, or a folder at `www.example.com/foo/`, or the like. I just need to be able to make changes at will to a single file.

We can't use a redirect or anything like that - the purpose of this is to allow me to control a document loaded in an `<iframe>` on their site, and for the JavaScript in that `<iframe>` to have access (i.e., no security restrictions) to its `parent` page - which is only allowed if the domains match. Their site doesn't change the `document.domain` property to relax the security restrictions, nor can we ask them to start using that approach (it's an enormous site).

I also can't generate an `<iframe>` and create its document solely using JavaScript - we've done that in the past, and it gets around the security restrictions (the generated `<iframe>` is in the same domain as its parent page), but it causes other issues and difficulties that add up to a deal-breaker in this case.

Please let me know if you have any alternative suggestions, or if you need any more information about what exactly I'm trying to do.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I'm understanding this correctly.  Since you have their permission to host a file on their site, can you just use FTP?  They can set you up to only be able to drop files in one directory on their site, and you can edit the file there.

Comment: Thanks, roberttdev - it sounds like you do understand what I'm trying to do. I've considered simply suggesting FTP, and I think that's probably the easiest solution to set up. I'm just not 100% sure if it's going to be OK for them to actually host the file vs. us - that's a business decision that I'll need others to decide. I'm mainly interested in whether there is an alternative to that that may have different pros & cons, in case I need a contingency plan.

Comment: I think I was overcomplicating things based on some strict business requirements. We ended up just sending them the file, and we'll ask them to update it themselves when needed. FTP would have been the simplest solution had we chosen to go that route. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Provide embed code to the other party to load remote javascript file to their page. You may then generate content or information gathering. As the javascript file is hosted on your side, it's under your control. A Visitor Counter is a similar case.

Comment: Thanks, benone - but that doesn't solve the problem of using <iframe>s and cross-frame access due to domain restrictions. There is one more detail that I failed to mention in my original question; I'll add that now.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a php script that loads it's data from your own site.
this should work actually:

```
<?php echo file_get_contents("http://www.yoursite.com/yourfile.html"); ?>
```

Edit: You might be able to do the same with javascript, but i don't know the code for it... Sorry. :-/

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your friend can set up a reverse proxy rule on their web server for your file. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html

Comment: Interesting - thanks for the suggestion. I'll discuss that with our back-end developers.